# How to create dynamic JSON object to populate the values from DB to draw Canvas charts?

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, html, javabeans

Requirement of the project is to draw the Bar/Pie charts using Canvas. As of now, I have created the charts using some static values. But the requirement is to get those values from MySQL Database server dynamically. I heard that JSON objects will be used to interchange the data.

Can anyone please share an example on how to populate the values from a JSON object from any DB server?

Comment: Just use an ajax call for getting a string representation of a Json then in your JavaScript parse it to an object.. JSON.parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the json from server and parse it with JSON.parse.

For drawing a canvas chart.

You can used this library javaScript plotting for jQuery - http://www.flotcharts.org/

It's will help you plot a graph via JSON data.

- For ajax update - http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/ajax/index.html
- For realtime update - http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/realtime/index.html

Sample static plot - http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/basic-usage/index.html

```
    var d1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 14; i += 0.5) {
        d1.push([i, Math.sin(i)]);
    }

    var d2 = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]];

    // A null signifies separate line segments

    var d3 = [[0, 12], [7, 12], null, [7, 2.5], [12, 2.5]];

    $.plot("#placeholder", [ d1, d2, d3 ]);
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

On server side Select your data from the database. Return data as a JSON string on page request.

Can use jquerys , getJSON function to get the, then plot the graph.

```
$.getJSON('pieinfo',function(data){
   var option = {
    series : {
       pie : {
         show:true
       }
    }
   };
   $.plot('#placeholder', data, option);
});
```